# Can I use AWS amplify framework to build a database intensive application like "Accounting"?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-amplify

Is it possible to use AWS amplify framework to build a database intensive application like "Accounting"?

If I want to use a serverless framework to develop an Accounting application what Serverless framework should I use "Lambda" or else? Is it really possible to implement a Serverless architecture for a database intensive application like Accounting or HR?

Comment: Possible? Probably. Is it the best option? That's for you to decide based on your particular use case.

Comment: Hey Welcome to to stack, so yes, although Amplify is mainly for mobile apps, if you just need serverless API's I'd look at Lambda, RDS/Dynamo